# Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one in Dev C++

Tags: c++

I converted `mysqlclient.lib to mysqlclient.a` using **ar** command

```
ar rcs mysqlclient.a mysqlclient.lib
```

now am keep getting that error    `Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one`

I run **ranlib** on `mysqlclient.a`  but still getting the above no index error :( do not know how to fix this , so need help

```
ranlib libmysqlclient.a
```

am using  dev c++ for my project

Comment: Or anybody have working mysqlclient.a lib please share download link :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

An Unix `libxyz.a` is an `ar(1)` archive of object (`.o`) files with an index created by `ranlib(1)` (AFAIU, GNU's `ar(1)` creates the index without requiring the extra step). You are creating a "library" out of a single `*.lib` file, so `ar(1)` won't create an index (no `.o` file in sight).

Where does the `.lib` comes from? What environment is this?

Comment: am in windows 7 , and its mysql client library ,  as am making my project in dev c++ so i have to convert .lib to .a  , actually i want static lib of mysql

Comment: There presumably `ar(1)` and `ranlib(1)` make no sense at all. There should be Windows-specific tools for this (or use a Unix-like anvironment, like Cygwin from the ground up).

Comment: ya i used cygwin for this ... i do not have linux installed so i use cgywin mostly